# How to change #+begin_comment .... #+end_comment background and text color?

Tags: spacemacs, font-lock, syntax-highlighting

When I have this code:

```
#+begin_comment
So this is my comment's body text. 
I want it to have these features:

1. text color will be yellow
2. background color will be blue
3. text will be cursive
#+end_comment
```

How to do that?

What code should I put in my .spacemacs config file?

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Comment: Thank you a lot, from the bottom of my heart, what would I do without people like you, Drew. This link will change my life. Again, thank you very, very much.

Comment: Welcome to emacs.stackexchange.com! We use tags to organize questions. It makes it easier for the regulars to find questions, and help people like yourself. In order for that system to work, we need to use the tags consistently. The elisp tag in particular gets used a lot more than it should, so we've been trying to encourage people to use it only in certain circumstances.

Answer (score 1):

This is from my `.emacs`:
 `'(org-meta-line ((t (:background "#0f0f0f" :foreground "azure4" :box (:line-width 1 :color "#0f0f0f")))))`

To do the same for you, set the face: `org-meta-line`.